# looping over filenames and modifying them

Tags: unix

The goal of my script is to iterate over all files with a .bam file extension and run an executable on them. I want the name of the output folder to be a modified version of the .bam file name.

Here is my current code:

```
for file in *.bam
do
 echo $file
 fq="" # this shouldnt be nessesary if that next asignmemt was working
 # do something on "$file"
 fq=$file | awk -F '[p]' '{print $1}' 
 echo "${fq}"
 fq="${fq}_Kolla_fastqs"
 echo "${fq}"

#./bamtofastq-1.2.0 $file $fq #exicutable to run later once the variable saving works
```

done

```
done
```

This is my output:

```
E14se_1_possorted.bam
E14se_1_

_Kolla_fastqs
E14se_2_possorted.bam
E14se_2_

_Kolla_fastqs
E16se_1_possorted.bam
E16se_1_

_Kolla_fastqs
E16se_2_possorted.bam
E16se_2_

_Kolla_fastqs
E16se_3_possorted.bam
E16se_3_

_Kolla_fastqs
P1se_1_possorted.bam
P1se_1_

_Kolla_fastqs
P1se_2_possorted.bam
P1se_2_

_Kolla_fastqs
P1se_3_possorted.bam
P1se_3_

_Kolla_fastqs
P1se_4_possorted.bam
P1se_4_

_Kolla_fastqs
P7se_4_possorted.bam
P7se_4_

_Kolla_fastqs
```

Comment: Try `fq=$(echo "$file" | awk ...)`

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ` symbol whenever you are adding values via an unix command to a variable.

For example,

fq=`$file | awk -F '[p]' '{print $1}'` 
echo "${fq}"
fq=`echo "${fq}_Kolla_fastqs"`
echo "${fq}"